# CodeIgniter Upload Image function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to CI and I am learning it through tutorials on Youtube. I am trying to upload image with what I found on tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ay_w82osHpM&list=PLeWSC4Y0oSoyO1HydYHDZ4ggRFBXxSVju&index=3) but unfortunately its not working. Below are the codes please help me.

Controller

```
public function create() {
$data['title'] = 'Create Post';
$data['desc'] = 'Feel free to create a new post here.';
$data['categories'] = $this->post_model->get_categories();

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Post Title', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Post Description', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
} else {
  // Upload Image
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = 2048;
  $config['max_width'] = 500;
  $config['max_height'] = 500;

  $this->upload->initialize($config);

  if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
  } else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  }

  $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
  return redirect('posts');
}
```

}

Model

```
public function create_post($post_image) {

$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));

$data = array(
  'post_title'  => $this->input->post('title'),
  'post_slug'   => $slug,
  'post_desc'   => $this->input->post('desc'),
  'post_cat_id' => $this->input->post('catid'),
  'post_image'  => $post_image
);

return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
```

}

View

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('posts/create'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Post Title</label>
  <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'title', 'placeholder'=>'Add Title', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value'=>set_value('title')]); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Select Category</label>
  <select name="catid" class="form-control">
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $category['cat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $category['cat_name']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Post Description</label>
  <?php echo form_textarea(['name'=>'desc', 'placeholder'=>'Add Description', 'class'=>'form-control', 'value'=>set_value('desc')]); ?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Upload Image</label>
  <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Post">
```

Now whenever I try to create a post with an image it executes `if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){` as TRUE and thus inserts `noimage.jpg` in database as well as image is not uploaded too. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**
On trying to DEBUG it using `print_r($this->upload->data()); die();` I got an empty list of array which means the file is not getting submitted from the form itself on the first place. But why? I don't find any error in the form.

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => 
    [file_type] => 
    [file_path] => ./assets/images/posts/
    [full_path] => ./assets/images/posts/
    [raw_name] => 
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => 
    [file_ext] => 
    [file_size] => 
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

and `print_r($errors)` give this error. I am close to solve now I guess.

```
Array
(
    [error] => 

The image you are attempting to upload doesn't fit into the allowed dimensions.

)
```

**SOLUTION**
I had to change the max_width and max_height to 0 for unlimited. The image was not being uploaded due to this error.

Comment: cross verify if you are uploading image with 500*500 and 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

Forget to load `upload` library do like this :

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

The whole code (file uploading part) should be like this :

```
else {
  // Upload Image
  $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH.'assets/images/posts';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = 2048;
  $config['max_width'] = 500;
  $config['max_height'] = 500;

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
  {
    print_r($this->upload->data());die;
    $file_name = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $post_image = $file_name; 
  } 
  else 
  {
    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    print_r($errors);die;
    $post_image = 'noimage.jpg'; 
  }

  $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
  return redirect('posts');
}
```

Comment: I have auto loaded the upload library which is the reason why I am using `$this->upload->initialize($config);` instead of `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` however its not working on both.

Comment: no error yet.. I don't know why its executing `if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){` as true. can you help?

Comment: just remove `upload` library from `autoload` and check it with my answer i  updated my answers pls check

Comment: Before using it as auto load I was already trying with the method you gave. Still I again did remove upload from auto load and manually set it again. Still its not working. There must be a mistake I am making which is not being able to get eye caught.

Comment: ok let debug it, use `print_r($this->upload->data());die;` in if part as given in my answer and in else part do like this :  `print_r($errors);die;` and check what is the output

Comment: I tried to do `print_r($this->upload->data());` after `$this->load->library('upload', $config);` and I got an empty array list. Which means maybe the file is not getting submitted from the form itself. But why? I am updating the error in the question.

Comment: Use `FCPATH` for the upload path an in my answer and make sure  its file permissions to 777.

Comment: so finally you got the problem ,ok what type of file you are uploading pls check first it should be png or jpg

Comment: Got the problem. The image dimensions (height and width that was set to 500) were creating the problem. I increased them to 5000 for testing and its working now. But then what is use of setting such height and width? I thought it would crop the image to 500x500 but it didn't.

Comment: max_width and max_height can be Set to zero for no limit. and for cropping you can use  Image Manipulation Class,

Comment: if my answer helps you pls don't hesitate to upvote and check my answer as green

Answer (score 0):

If you think your code is correct. Have you checked folder permissions?
You have to give permission to folders in order to store images

Answer (score 0):

try following changes

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts'; **to** $config['upload_path'] = getcwd().'/assets/images/posts';
```

Answer (score 0):

You must remove library upload from autoloading and edit code like this.

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
} else {
  // Upload Image
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = 2048;
  $config['max_width'] = 500;
  $config['max_height'] = 500;

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);
  $this->upload->initialize($config);
  if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
  } else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  }

  $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
  return redirect('posts');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code!

```
 public function create() {
$data['title'] = 'Create Post';
$data['desc'] = 'Feel free to create a new post here.';
$data['categories'] = $this->post_model->get_categories();

$this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Post Title', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('desc', 'Post Description', 'required');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
} else {
  // Upload Image
  $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/posts';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
  $config['max_size'] = 2048;
  $config['max_width'] = 500;
  $config['max_height'] = 500;

  $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
    $errors = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $post_image = 'noimage.jpg';
  } else {
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $post_image = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  }

  $this->post_model->create_post($post_image);
  return redirect('posts');
}
```

Comment: And what does it do? Kindly explain it more.